# How to make an OCaml definition for a given syntax definition?

Tags: syntax, ocaml, definition

I'm newbie in OCaml. I have a syntax definition like below:

```
<program>::= 
| <instruction <program>>
| "end"
<instruction>::=
| "move"
| "left"
| "right"
| "repeat" <program>
```

How can I write an OCaml definition for it? Something like: "let p =..."

Comment: You should explain what you really want. The definition of data structure for this syntax tree, or the parser for this syntax, or the both? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, when you give someone a grammar, you should specify in what language it is written, e.g., EBNF. Your example doesn't look as a valid BNF for me.

Although, if I understand your definition correctly, then the `program` and `instruction` will map to the following OCaml types:

```
type program = 
  | Instruction of instruction
  | End
and instruction = 
  | Move
  | Left
  | Right
  | Repeat of program
```

In order to transform an arbitrary string to the value of the above defined program type you need to write a parser. A usual way in OCaml to write parsers is to use `ocamllex` and `ocamlyacc` tools. But this simple grammar can be parsed manually. The following function will parse a list of tokens and output a program:

```
let rec parse = function
  | ["instruction"; "move" ]  -> Instruction Move
  | ["instruction"; "left" ]  -> Instruction Left
  | ["instruction"; "right"]  -> Instruction Right
  | "instruction" :: "repeat" :: tokens  -> Instruction (Repeat (parse tokens))
  | ["end"] -> End
  | [] -> invalid_arg "Unexpected end of stream"
  | token :: _ -> invalid_arg ("Unexpected token: " ^ token)
```

The list of tokens should be produced by the so named tokenizer (or lexer), a function that takes a string and splits it into a list of tokens. A simple tokenizer can be written using `Str` library:

```
let tokenizer = Str.(split (regex " +"))
```

As a side note: `Str` library is not loaded into toplevel by default. In order to load it, you need to issue following directives to toplevel (including # symbols):

```
#use "topfind";;
#require "str";;
```

Comment: I think that *instruction <program>* actually represents a sequence of instructions. That implies substantial changes to your post, so I refrained from editing it.

Comment: I think so too, but I'm not going to solve the whole problem set for OP, my goal is to give a starting point.